# Configuring log4j2 to have different log levels for different packages

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j2

I want to configure log4j2 to log my application. I want to log my application with log level DEBUG, but hibernate with log level ERROR.

I looked into the documentation (here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) and read other sites too, but couldn't resolve my problem of rightly configuring log4j2.

```
    public static void init(String name) {

        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
        builder.setConfigurationName("BuilderTest");
        builder.add(builder.newFilter("ThresholdFilter", Filter.Result.ACCEPT, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                .addAttribute("level", Level.DEBUG));

        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE")
                .addAttribute("target",ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
                .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newFilter("MarkerFilter", Filter.Result.DENY, Filter.Result.NEUTRAL)
                .addAttribute("marker", "FLOW"));
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

        builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.mypackage", Level.DEBUG)
                .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout"))
                .addAttribute("additivity", false));

//        builder.add(builder.newLogger("org.hibernate", Level.ERROR)
//                .add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout"))
//                .addAttribute("additivity", false));

        builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR).add(builder.newAppenderRef("Stdout")));

        LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
        logger = ctx.getLogger(name);
    }
```

What I tried is to use the packages names to set specific log levels for each one and to try different levels for the loggers/root logger but in the end I get always too much information (e.g. my debug messages and the debug messages from hibernate) or too less information.

How do I correctly configure log4j2 to fit my needs?

Comment: Why do you need to configure log4j2 with Java code? The regular configuration file options are not sufficient?

Comment: I found it more convenient for me. Why do you ask?

Comment: Why specifically is it more convenient? It's generally a last resort, it means logging is configured late and errors are very hard to diagnose. Just take [an example config file](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j-2-xml-configuration-example/) and adapt it.

Comment: I'm fine switching to other methods using files if you recommend it. That's what I'm here for: getting help! As long as I get my initial problem solved, I'm up to everything.

Comment: I think if you take some time to read over the examples on the [architecture page of the log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) and the [configuration page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Loggers) it would help you greatly. I think any answer posted here would just be restating what these pages already cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to my answer. I don't know if it is the correct way of doing it, but it works for me. Here is my log4j2.xml (done via the config file instead of doing it programatically):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.mypackage" level="DEBUG"/>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR"/>

        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

With this, the code in mypackage will be logged in the DEBUG level and hibernate will be logged in the ERROR level.

Comment: The looks very much like the correct (and also simplest) way :-)